# "object 'BigQuery' not found" using dplyr and bigrquery

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been trying to connect to my bigquery project using dplyr, but since the `bigrquery` library isn't available in CRAN, I used devtools to install them from github.

Connection went fine, but trying to create a table object didn't work. Here's what I tried so far

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("bigrquery")
devtools::install_github("lazy")
devtools::install_github("dplyr")

library(bigrquery)
library(dplyr)

project <- "project"
dataset <- "dataset"

bq <- src_bigquery(project, dataset)
sometable <- tbl(bq, "table")
```

And getting this error:

> Error in query.bigquery(x$src$con, sql, vars) :    object 'BigQuery'
>   not found

Comment: It's broken at the moment. Will fix in a week or two

Comment: Thanks! dplyr is awesome by the way!